# How to fix this Base 64 array issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a base64 string in the `view` side. If I pass the whole `base64` array at a time I can convert that in to bytes like this

```
  byte[] myBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
```

where `data` represents the data that is coming form the view page. But I am having huge data. So, I am splitting the data in the view page like

```
var arr = [];  
for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i += 1000000) {
   arr.push(data.substr(i, 1000000));
}
```

And now I am passing the data to the controller

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {           
   if (x = 0) {
      r = "first";
   }
   else if (x = arr.length - 1) {
       r = "last";
   }
   else {
       r = "next";
   }
   $.post('/Home/Content', { content: e, data: r }, function (d) {

   });
}
```

And in the controller side I have written code like:

```
public JsonResult Content(string content, string data)
{
   datavalueincont += content;

   if (data == "last")
   {
       byte[] myBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(datavalueincont);
       var fname = "D://sri//data.mp4";
       FileStream stream = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
       System.IO.BinaryWriter br = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream);
       br.Write(myBinary);
       br.Close();               
       read.Close();
       stream.Close();
   }

   return Json("suc", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But I am getting error at:

```
byte[] myBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(datavalueincont);
```

and that error is

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

How can I rectify this. If I pass the data at a time I am able to get the bytes in the 
`myBinary` array. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: "i am getting error" - what kind of error?

Comment: **i < data.length - 1**  why -1 ?

Comment: what is `e` in `{ content: e, data: r }`? shouldn't be `{ content: arr[x], data: r }`?

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea.

As you are sending your data using Ajax, nothing ensures you that your chunks will be sent sequentially.

So maybe when you aggregate your data your chunks are not in a good order.

Try to make your Ajax call sequentially to confirm this point.

**[Edit]**

something like this (not tested):

```
var data = [];//your data

var sendMoreData = function (firstTime) {
    if (data.length == 0)
        return;//no more data to send

    var content = data.shift();
    var r = firstTime ? "first" :
            data.length == 0 ? "last":
            "next";

    $.post('/Home/Content', { content: content, data: r }, function (d) {
        sendMoreData();
    });
};

sendMoreData(true);
```

Comment: @polkduran Thank you for your wonderful idea. I have solved this. And i have also changed the `filereader` to `streamreader`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `byte[] myBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(datavalueincont);` until you have the fully encrypted string.
The problem is that you're splitting the Base64 data into chunks after which you send those chunks to the server -> on the server you're trying to convert back from base64 on each individual chunk rather than the whole collection of chunks.

The way I see it, you have 2 options:

1. Encrypt each individually split chunk of data to base64 (rather than the whole thing before hand) and decrypt it on the server.
2. Encrypt the whole thing, then split it into pieces (like you're doing now) -> send it to the server -> cache each result (any way you
   want -> session, db etc.) till you get the last one -> decrypt at
   once

As a side note:

```
if (x = 0) {
   r = "first";
}
else if (x = arr.length - 1) {
   r = "last";
}
```

should really be:

```
if (x == 0) {
   r = "first";
}
else if (x == arr.length - 1) {
   r = "last";
}
```

Not sure if typo, just sayin'.

Comment: Ok how do we get the full encrypted string

Comment: No i am converting from whole collection of chunks. I am appending the chunks to a `string` which is defined globally. When the enters the `if` condition of last then i am converting the whole chunks. Hope you understand

Comment: Break it up before converting to base64, then convert it back and concatenate, or concatenate then convert from base 64

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yep, exactly what I mean.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I am doing like that only

Comment: I am concatenating and then converting still i am getting this

Answer (score 0):

I think your concept is fine... from what I understand you are doing the following...

1. View converts binary data to Base64String
2. View splits string into chunks and sends to controller
3. Controller waits for all chunks and concatenates them
4. Controller converts from Base64String

The problem is in how you are splitting your data in the view... I am assuming the splitting code has some extra padding characters on the end maybe?

```
var arr = [];  
for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i += 1000000) {
   arr.push(data.substr(i, 1000000));
}
```

I can't build a test rig to check the code but certainly on your last section of text you can't get 1000000 characters from .substr because there aren't that many characters in the string.  I don't know what .substr will return but I would troubleshoot the splitting section of code to find the problem.

Comment: I was thinking something like concatentaion introducing some garbage into the string that after reading the OPs further comments. Another possibility would be chunks being assembled in a different order.

Comment: Hopefully he will respond and say what the problem ended up being.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `datavalueincont += content;` is really aggregating all your data. How do you store `datavalueincont` after each http request?

Maybe you are only missing that.

Have you debugged when `data == "last"` to see if you have all your data in `datavalueincont` ?

Comment: Yah i have all the data. I am not sure why it is working like that. Is this the correct procedure i am doing